# Разное время в результатах запросов

Tags: sql-server, ssms

Коллеги, приветствую)

Выявили такую проблему, что если обращаться к одной и той же таблице, но из разных регионов, то вывод результата в SSMS отличается. Таблица без вычисляемы столбцов.
И результат такой, к примеру:

Коллега1 из МСК видит: 2023-03-24 **08**:24:00.843

Коллега2 из НСК видит: 2023-03-24 **08**:24:00.843

Коллега3 из НСК видит: 2023-03-24 **11**:24:00.843

Коллега4 из НСК видит: 2023-03-24 **11**:24:00.843

Т.е. тут даже нет корреляции от региона, т.к. у одного коллеги из НСК результаты совпадают с коллегой из МСК.

Кто сталкивался, подскажите куда смотреть)

*Есть подозрение, что дело в настройках студии, т.к. обращение идёт к одному экземпляру, БД и таблице в ней, но вроде всё проглядел и ничего подобного не обнаружил.*

Comment: Дело не в регионе, а в настройках зон времени на клиентских станциях.